# Decomposição em primos

Tags: c++, algoritmo, matemática, lógica

Olá pessoal estou aprendendo C++ pra matéria de Estrutura de Dados e tem algum erro no código que está criando um loop infinito.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int fatores(int a[], int n, int *x) {
    int primo = 2;    // primeiro primo
    int qtdzero = 0;  // incrementa sempre que o resto do número der zero.
    int divisoes = n; // só recebe do parâmetro
    int count = 0;    // contador pra pular o endereço do vetor a

    while (divisoes > 1) {   // vai sair do loop quando divisão chegar a 1
     bool sair = true; 
     for (int i = 1 ; i <= primo ; i++) {
         if (primo % i == 0) {     //teste se é primo ou não
             qtdzero++;
         }
     }
     if (qtdzero == 2) {   //se for primo entra aqui.
         while (sair) {
            if ((divisoes % primo == 0) && (divisoes >= primo)) {
                a[count++] = primo;   //armazena o primo
                divisoes = divisoes / primo;
                (*x)++;
            } else {
                sair = false;
                primo++;
            }
         }
     } else { // se falso, passa pro próximo número e faz o mesmo teste
         primo++;
         qtdzero = 0;
     }
    }
    return ((*x > 10) ? 1 : 0); // retorna quantidade de decomposições
}

int main() {
  int *a = new int[20]; //guarda os números primos
  int *x = new int; // guarda a quantidade de vezes que foi decomposto
  int res = fatores(a, 24, x);

  printf("%i\n", res); // printa o retorno da função fatores

  for (int i = 0; i < 20 ; i++) // exibe os valores decompostos
    printf("%i\n", a[i]);
}
```

Comment: Se der tempo eu dou uma olhada mas o código é muito confuso, realmente é fácil se perder aí dentro. Tenho certeza que se ele fosse escrito de outra forma o erro não aconteceria.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O código realmente está meio confuso. Ele está entrando em loop infinito porque `divisoes` começa em 24, depois passa a valer 12, então 6 e por fim 3. Quando `divisoes` tem 3 não entra nessa condição:

```
if ((divisoes % primo == 0) && (divisoes >= primo))
```

Isso ocorre a primeira vez quando `primo` tem 2 e o resto da divisão não é zero. O código cai nesse `else` mais interno:

```
else 
{
     sair = false;
     primo++;
}
```

Aqui ele não zera a variável `qtdzero` que define se o número é primo ou não assim ele não vai fazer o teste quando `primo` valer 3. Ele só vai voltar a fazer o teste quando primo for 5, pois quando 3 entrou no segundo `else` e zerou `qtdzero`.
Para não alterar muito a sua forma de construção do código faça assim:

```
if ((divisoes % primo == 0) && (divisoes >= primo)) 
{
     a[count++] = primo;
     divisoes = divisoes / primo;
     (*x)++;
} 
else 
{
     sair = false;
     primo++;
     qtdzero = 0;
}
```

Comment: Obrigado por responder mas ainda estou na dúvida, no caso quando chegar a 3 ele faria  3 % 2 == 0 o que dá falso, dai ele vai pro else que incrementa o primo, voltando para o primeiro while fazendo os mesmo procedimento ?
No caso, primo valeria 3 e entraria no if, divisoes iria para 1 e sairia do primeiro while.

Comment: Funcionou, foi só aquela qtdzero que eu esqueci de zerar. Obrigado
Obs: eu vi outros exemplos de decomposição bem mais simples, eu realmente tenho que praticar mais.